# React native Press Cmd+M does not work

Tags: reactjs, keyboard, native, reload

I am newbie

I work with react native but I have one problem

1. I run this command "react-native run-android"
2. I press R-R from my keyboard but app not reload
3. I press Cmd+M to open Menu but nothing happen
4. I open Android Studio and sure that I config debug for app
5. I try to open form sign in and press r-r, my keyboard is working

Now my question is: How can I reload app react native?

Config debug: [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6F9HH.png)
keyboard is working: [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R6x5r.png)

Comment: shake the phone and press reload when the menu comes up? or run `adb shell input keyevent KEYCODE_MENU` to open the menu

Comment: Thank @John Ruddell
I run on android emulator
and I tried to run `adb shell input keyevent KEYCODE_MENU`
and `adb shell input keyevent 82`
but it does not work

Comment: Hmm, I have the exact same issue as of today. I upgraded react native using react-native-git-upgrade to 0.47 (a downgrade as the scrollview currently broken) and now it doesn't work. You have similar experience?

Answer (score 2):

Check your Build Variants in the android panel.
The release version does not support Ctrl+m

Comment: oof u helped me